# How can I interpolate data in python?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a 4D dataset `(time, z, y, x)` and I would like to interpolate the data to get a higher resolution, this is a simple example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x_0 = 10
cut_index = 10

res = 200j
x_index = x_0
y_index = np.linspace(0, 100, 50).astype(int)
z_index = np.linspace(0, 50, 25).astype(int)

#Time, zyx-coordinate
u = np.random.randn(20, 110, 110, 110)

z_index, y_index = np.meshgrid(z_index, y_index)
data = u[cut_index, z_index, y_index, x_index]


res = 200j
y_f = np.mgrid[0:100:res]
z_f = np.mgrid[0:50:res]
z_f, y_f = np.meshgrid(z_f, y_f)

data = griddata((z_index, y_index), data, (z_f, y_f))
```

I am getting the `ValueError: invalid shape for input data points` error. What kind of input is expected by the `griddata` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` parameter has to be a 1D array. Try flattening the arrays:

```
data = griddata((z_index.flatten(), y_index.flatten()), data.flatten(), (z_f, y_f))
```